why won't Flutter stop using my default ic_launcher icon?
I'm new to Flutter and for some reason, it keeps showing me a launch screen that has nothing to do with the launch_background.xml. It shows me the default flutter icon over a white background, despite the launch_bacground file has the image commented-out by default and even if I completely change the file. What am I doing wrong? Here are the full steps:

Created a new app using flutter create flutter1

flutter build apk --debug

flutter run --debug shows the default launch screen I mentioned on my emulator

I try to change my launcher xml, for example, use some custom image (I have the img2.png in the drawable subfolders):


<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="?android:colorBackground" />

    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@mipmap/img2" />
    </item>
</layer-list>

I even remove the <item> image altogether - doesn't matter. It still shows me the default flutter logo. How do I resolve this?
